# Why is the line not drawing for my line graph d3 javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, linegraph

I am fairly new to using javascript and d3. I am trying to draw a line chart and have the data organized and the graph drawn besides the actual line.

Here is what I have currently

```
function drawLineChart(){
    lsvg.selectAll("*").remove();

    var width = 975;
    var height = 600;

    var xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date(1990,01,01),new Date(2013,01,01)]).range([0,width-150]);
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height-100,0]);
    var g = lsvg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(" + 50+ "," + 50 + ")");


    var aids = d3.csv('data/aids.csv').then(function(data){
        var maxx = d3.max(data, function(d){return d["Data.AIDS-Related Deaths.All Ages"]});
        yScale.domain([0, maxx]);
        g.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(20,500)") 
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(d3.timeYear))
            .append("text")
            .attr("y",40)
            .attr("x",350)
            .attr("stroke","black")
            .attr("fill","black")
            .attr("font-size",25)
            .text("Year");
        g.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(function(d){return d;}).ticks(10))
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(270)")
            .attr("y", -50)
            .attr("x",-150)
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            .attr("fill","black")
            .attr("font-size",25)
            .text('AIDS-Related Deaths');
        
    });
    let line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d){return xScale(d.Year);})
        .y(function(d){return yScale(d.value);});

    

    var tempData = getDataSet("Afghanistan");

    g.append("path")
        .data(tempData)
        .attr("class","line")
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("stroke-width",5)
        .attr("d",line);    

    
}
```

I have tried changing a few things around for a while now and just cannot figure out the issue. I think it may have something to do with the scale. I think a fresh pair of eyes might be able to spot something. here is the data that the function getDataSet returns:

```
0
: 
{value: '100', Year: '1990'}
1
: 
{value: '100', Year: '1991'}
2
: 
{value: '100', Year: '1992'}
....
30
: 
{value: '1000', Year: '2020'}
```

Comment: Try `.datum(tempData)` instead of `.data(tempData)`.

Comment: I did unfortunately it wasnt the issue :/

Comment: That **is** an issue, it has to be `datum` in that situation. Now you have to find the remaining issues.